# How many JS statements get processed per event loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

Is there a set number of <s>instructions</s> statements that get processed before checking the event queue/per tick/per loop (ways of saying the same thing, I think?)

Comment: I would imagine that depends almost entirely on how much processing power is available.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Node runs the entire input script before it processes the event loop. How many instructions that is depends on the script. If you're script has a never ending `while` loop, it will never process the even loop.

Comment: @MarkMeyer good point, I'm referring to "initial commands" if that makes sense (for example, instructions executed with an empty stack.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a set number of instructions that get processed before checking the event queue/per tick/per loop (ways of saying the same thing, I think?)

No, there is not.

In the node.js architecture, when an event is pulled from the event queue, it's tied to a callback.  The interpreter calls that callback and that callback runs to completion.  Only when it returns and the stack is again empty does it check to see if there is another event in the event queue to run.

So, it has absolutely nothing to do with a number of instructions.  node.js runs your Javascript as single-threaded so there is no time slicing between pieces of Javascript which it sounds like your question perhaps was anticipating.  Once a callback is called that corresponds to an even in the event queue, that callback runs until it finishes and returns control back to the interpreter.

So, it goes like this:

1. Pull event from the event queue
2. Call the Javascript callback associated with that event
3. Javascript callback runs until completion and then returns from the callback
4. node.js internals check event queue for next event.  If an event is there, go to step 1 and repeat
5. If no event is there, go to sleep until an event is placed into the event queue.

In reality, this is a bit of a simplification because there are several different types of event queues with a priority order for which one gets to go first, but this describes the general process as it relates to your question.

Comment: Got it - so basically one full instruction until it runs to completion (e.g. the stack is flushed) per event loop tick?

Comment: @AdamThompson - Your use of the term "instruction" in that sentence seems confusing to me.  Typically in a computer architecture, an instruction is a low-level operation (like move this value into that register or move this value into that variable).  Using that definition, there could be anywhere from only a few instructions to millions of instructions to run the callback to completion, depending entirely upon what the callback does.  But, you are correct that the stack will unwind and be empty when the callback is done and that's when it then looks for the next event.

Comment: I agree it's confusing, but not sure what else to call it. :) I changed the question to refer to statements which is probably more apt (I don't think expression is correct here.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no set number of instructions that get processed before checking the event queue. Each message is run to completion. From the Mozilla documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop):

> Each message is processed completely before any other message is processed. This offers some nice properties when reasoning about your program, including the fact that whenever a function runs, it cannot be pre-empted and will run entirely before any other code runs (and can modify data the function manipulates). This differs from C, for instance, where if a function runs in a thread, it may be stopped at any point by the runtime system to run some other code in another thread.
>
> A downside of this model is that if a message takes too long to complete, the web application is unable to process user interactions like click or scroll. The browser mitigates this with the "a script is taking too long to run" dialog. A good practice to follow is to make message processing short and if possible cut down one message into several messages.

Comment: Is it just one message (and all of it's sub-messages) per event loop/tick? In other words, everytime the stack clears then the loop ticks?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by sub-messages, but each message does constitute one tick. Messages are added to the queue, and thus are processed in FIFO order. If one message results in more messages being processed, then they will execute after all other messages already in the queue have been processed. I'd recommend reading through the link I provided, I believe it answers your question in greater detail (particularly in the Queue and Event Loop sections).